# The oneui_idx_v1.3 Dojo Extension mobile theme not rendering properly for XPages Mobile Controls

Tags: mobile, xpages, xpages-extlib

In the Xsp Properties when I change from the Mobile default theme to the OneUI IDX v1.3 common UI theme all of my "mobilePageName.xsp" pages no longer render properly.

The following are the related properties set in xsp.properties :

```
  xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix=mobile
  xsp.theme.mobile=oneui_idx_v1.3
```

I tested on Domino 9.0.1 FP2 and again on local web preview for Designer 9.0.1 FP2 ... same result, always broken rendering when testing with the oneui_idx_v1.3 theme.
[image: oneui_idx_v1.3 theme rendering]

They all render properly when I remove the xsp.theme.mobile=oneui_idx_v1.3 from the xsp.properties to return to render using the default mobile theme.
[image: same xpage using default mobile theme]

**Added image showing developer tools and page head.**
Note ... I am running 9.0.1 FP2 with no additional hot fixes applied ... am wondering now if the hot fix to correct the iOS8 problem with the mobile controls will also fix this oneui_idx theme problem, but cannot apply the fix right now.
[image]

Comment: seems like a CSS is missing. Can you check using the developer tools to verify if there is a 404?

Comment: Does not appear to be a 404 error ... unless I'm not looking in right place.  I added image above with developer tools enabled.

Comment: @Stephan ... I am running 9.0.1 FP2 with no additional hot fixes applied ... am wondering now if the hot fix to correct the iOS8 problem with the mobile controls will also fix this oneui_idx theme problem, but cannot apply the fix right now.

Comment: You looked at the right place and yes the hotfix does fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed when I applied [Domino 9.0.1 Fix Pack 2 Interim Fix 1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963) which includes Dojo 1.9.4.

Was actually surprised that the hot fix would do the trick because all the discussion in the community and in the [technote 1686751](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21686751) was focused only on fixing the iOS 8.x support for the Mobile Controls.  Turns out the OneUI IDX v1.3 theme also needs Dojo 1.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the full theme file name:

```
xsp.theme.mobile=oneui_idx_v1.3.theme
```

Comment: No, that didn't do it ... same result :(